# Highlighting current page as active link in included navigation menu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, menu

I have a static menu in the sidebar which I include in every JSF page. The menu looks like so:

```
  <li class="nav-header">Item 1</li>
  <li class="active"><a href="index.xhtml">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="new_workload.xhtml">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="import_workload.xhtml">Item 4</a></li>
```

Adding a `class="active"` to the `<li>` highlights the menu. How do I go about making sure selected item is highlighted dynamically in JSF2?

I know PrimeFaces and RichFaces have ready made components for this, but I want to try a pure JSF 2 solution first. A pure client side JavaScript solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can get the current view ID in EL as follows

```
#{view.viewId}
```

So, this should do

```
class="#{view.viewId eq '/index.xhtml' ? 'active' : ''}"
```

It'd be easier to hold all those links in some `List<Page>` so that you can just do something like

```
<li class="nav-header">#{menu.header}</li>
<ui:repeat value="#{menu.pages}" var="page">
    <li class="#{view.viewId eq page.viewId ? 'active' : ''}">
        <h:link value="#{page.title}" outcome="#{page.viewId}" />
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

instead of copypasting the same piece of code over and over.

Comment: Thank you BaluSC.! What would newcomers to JSF do without you:-) Appreciate your patience in answering all these noob questions...

Comment: can you suggest some solution when menu item updates the partial page via ajax. and not the complete page is refreshed. i can do it with a javascript callback on menu click. but what could be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, @BalusC, you always save us. It's time to Stack Exchange to create a BalusC Response Community.  kkk

Comment: thank you @BalusC !! really this is an extra magic, but how to make it works with menus and sub-menus ?

Comment: @Spartan: have `Page` a `List<Page> pages` property representing child pages.

Comment: @BalusC : and what about the condition `"#{view.viewId eq page.viewId ? 'active' : ''}"` and how to get 2 parameters from `view.viewId`

Comment: Do you recommend to store those pages in a database or just as List of a `@ApplicationScoped` bean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer BalusC
How would you do it if the outcome page is always the same but with different parameters ?
I tried something like: #{view.viewId eq '/tcsinstance.xhtml?tcs='+o.dir ? 'active' : ''} 
But this doesn't work...
Full Link looks like this: http://localhost:8080/tcs-web/faces/tcsinstance.xhtml?tcs=tcs02_7040&host=mqzhltcs02&port=7040

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've used @BalusC idea plus his other tip at [12473461](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473461/twitter-bootstrap-jsf-2-active-menu-style) but with **some modification**:

```
<ul>
  <li class="#{view.viewId eq '/admin/index.xhtml' ? 'active' : ''}"><h:link value="Main" outcome="main"/></li>
  <li class="#{fn:startsWith(view.viewId, '/admin/sess1/') ? 'active' : ''}"><h:link value="Session 1" outcome="sess1"/></li>
  <li class="#{fn:startsWith(view.viewId, '/admin/sess2/') ? 'active' : ''}"><h:link value="Session 2" outcome="sess2"/></li>
  <li class="#{fn:startsWith(view.viewId, '/admin/sess3/') ? 'active' : ''}"><h:link value="Session 3" outcome="sess3"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on custom component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" >
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="outcome" />
    <composite:attribute name="label" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <li class="menuItem #{view.viewId == cc.attrs.outcome ? 'active' : ''}">
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.label}" rendered="#{view.viewId eq cc.attrs.outcome}"/>
        <h:link outcome="#{cc.attrs.outcome}" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" rendered="#{view.viewId ne cc.attrs.outcome}" />
    </li>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Used in code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/my">
...
<ul class="nav">
     <my:menuItem outcome="/home.xhtml" label="Home" />
</ul>
```

Comment: A simple facelet tag would be sufficient here as well