# How to change the color of the current selected menuitem?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menuitem

I have a submenu in PrimeFaces that contains many menuitems, I would like to color it when it's selected in order to show to the user the current menuitem.

```
                <p:submenu label="Books" style="width:60%; color:#FFFFFF; background:#db4455;"
                               icon="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh">
                        <p:menuitem 
                            style="width:95%; font-weight:bold; background:#93c3cd; color:#FFFFFF;"
                            value="Action" url="action.xhtml"  /> 
                        <p:menuitem 
                            style="width:95%; font-weight:bold; background:#93c3cd; color:#FFFFFF;"
                            value="Fiction" url="fiction.xhtml"  /> 
                </p:submenu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way.

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.ui-menuitem-link').each(function(){
       if(window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) != -1) {
           $(this).css('background', 'red');//or add class
       }
   });  

})
```

**See Also :**

- [Highlighting selected menu (Another approach)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094429/highlighting-selected-menu)

Comment: This solution would be hard when we provide theme switcher for user to change the theme color. I expect PF has default attribute for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<p:menuitem action="resoluciones" value="Resoluciones" style="color :#{expediente.samattramite eq 20 ? '#990000' : 'black'};"/>
```

I dont know how your application is developed, but in my case i have a variable (expediente.samattramite) wich change of value when I change the screen ¿view? (xhtml, sorry for my lenguage) or active some functionality to know in what state I am

Comment: How do you know in this case the menuitem is selected? It looks more like conditionally styling it, but the condition not being 'it is selected'

Comment: I dont know how your application is developed, but in my case i have a variable (expediente.samattramite) wich change of value when I change the screen ¿view? (xhtml, sorry for my lenguage)  or active some functionality to know in what state I am.

Comment: Then please add that to your answer on **how** you store that. That is not clear and very important.

Comment: I've just added the comment yo the answer. Excuse me, just trying to help

Comment: I (we all?) appreciate the help, and I want to help improving the quality of answers. It still is not clear how you set the variable in your application. Can you add something about that?

Comment: Ok, Im a newbie but i though you must discuss about the topic, im going to leave the site. tired about the forum gods. Despite im a newbie, i guess i cant help.

Comment: I'm not a god, human of flesh and blood  (and an aging brain). Help is good, and being a newbie is not a problem at all, trying to help is good. But since I do not understand/see how you save/store the page you are on, I'm looking/requesting for clarification

Comment: Ok, sorry, just a little embaraced, less than a year developing java and i dont understand quite well your question, look, the code is huge, I have many subflows when I click on a command link (each one has his own action associated) I jump from one flow to another, all of them, has the same parent-flow, wich is associated with a Controller, lets call it "ParentController" the xhtml asociated to the chlids sub-flow acces to this variable and draw one thing or another depending of the variable. More than 25000 lines of code. Dont know what i should paste. Sorry again

Comment: A co-worker suggests me to store in session a value representing the selected option and compare this value with de equivalent menuitem during rendering, so you can distinguish which color is needed.

Comment: Yes, but your answer does not contain that information and no example code on how to do that. If you add an example of that, your answer is 'complete' and good ;-)

Comment: Ok, understand. On 18 of April i will write my first post (Is necessary enough reputation?) and ill explain it with examples. Sorry again for my bad manners. Hope this information help somebody :)

Comment: is not bad manners, don't feel ashamed... Good luck further (I'll help out with improving if needed!)